# Long load times of webpage assets

Tags: html, web, hosting, web-hosting, cdn

I have a website that runs just fine on my local server. It's quick, responsive, and overall runs great.

But when I put it on the server of my domain host, sometimes it takes excessively long to load assets. For example, one 1MB **png** file took 2.31 seconds to load:

[image]

Chrome's Network Developer Tool reveals to me the following:

[image]

So is this likely due to poor implementation of my code or is it possibly a crappy server? (The company is subscribing at the lowest tier possible to host their content) My internet connection is quick so I doubt it's that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably a problem with your host. An image is an image :) there aren't a 100 ways to implement one!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's assume that I'm a complete idiot (as I've been known to be one from time to time haha), can you think of anything that I could have possibly screwed up to cause this? Worst-case scenario kind of thing?

Comment: Well, what languages did you use ? Plain html ?

Comment: HTML/PHP/JS encompass the entire site but in this particular loading of the asset, the JS is making a call to apply the PNG file from above.

Comment: As of the loading time itself, there is no other transfer than from the host to your client. Also, if your code was flawed, you would notice it in localhost too :)

Answer (score 1):

Oversized images always take longer to load, so you should keep your images as small as possible.To lower down the content download time, you can optimize/compress the image without degrading it's visual quality.If you are using any graphics software to optimize the images, you should use “Save for Web” option. This will reduce the size of images and hence image  load time.

Furthermore, you can use CDN to serve static assets of your website like, images, CSS,JS, videos, etc. A CDN populates your website files to geographically distributed network of servers called POPs. CDN serves the website resources from the nearest geographical location of a visitor, that means your website assets will load more faster.

Use SSD based host. SSD has excellent read/write rates compared to that of traditional HDDs. Hence, solid state drives perform better than hard disk drives and they are almost 100 times faster than traditional HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a question for you

Is the image you're trying to load in background, or its an image tag?

Comment: If it's a background, you can put a copy as an inline image you want to expedite near the top of your HTML in a tiny div with no overflow - that way, by the time the background is being pulled in, the image has already loaded.